# Zeppelin - Dynamic Form - How to create masked field for entering passwords

Tags: markdown, apache-zeppelin

I am using Zeppelin Dynamic Forms and I can able to create a text box using the below command thereby I can pass value during runtime and process it.

```
%md Hello ${name}
```

What if I want to create a text box to get the value for passwords which should be masked (typically with asterisks or any other characters). Is there any way to achieve this in Zeppelin ?

Answer (score 1):

Password input is available in master branch [ZEPPELIN-2528. Add a password text input to the ZeppelinContext](https://github.com/apache/zeppelin/pull/3041) and will be in version 0.9 (no plans)

Current released [branch 0.8](https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=zeppelin.git;a=shortlog;h=refs/heads/branch-0.8) doesn't have this functionality.